# How can I get the depth intensity from kinect depth image since it respresents distance of pixel from sensor

Tags: image-processing, kinect, depth, openkinect, kinect-v2

Recently i read a paper , they extract depth intensity and distance of pixel from camera using depth image. But, as far I know, each pixel value in depth image represents distance in mm [range:0-65536] then how can they extract depth intensity within a range [0 to 255] from depth image. I don't understand it. kinect sensor returns uint16 depth frame which includes the each pixel distance from sensor. It does not return any intensity value, then how can the paper demonstrates that they extract depth intensity . I am really confused.

[Here is the paper link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxE0m87JWnjVNjg3dlpaQk1XNUE)

This is the graph what I want to extract(collected from the paper:

[image: img]

Comment: I do not see any definition of the depth intensity therm ... it may have different meaning then the name suggest.

Comment: what is the meaning ?

Comment: well that is the question ... most likely only the authors of the paper can answer ...

Comment: no reply from him.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no an answer for this question , i will suggest you approach for getting your own depth image data .

One simple way can be scaling the image based on following formula:

```
    Pixel_value=Pixel_value/4500*65535
```

If you want see the exact image that you get from uint8 ; I guess the following steps will work for you.

Probably while casting the image to uint8 matlab firstly clip the values above some threshold lets say  `4095=2**12-1` (i'm not sure about value) and then it makes right shifts (4 shifts in our case) to make it inside the range of 0-255.

So i guess multiplying the value of uint8 with 256 and casting it as uint16 will help you get the same image

```
        Pixel_uint16_value= Pixel_uint8_value*256 //or Pixel_uint16_value= Pixel_uint8_value<<8 
        //dont forget to cast the result as uint16
```

The other way to converting raw data to depth image in millimeters.

The depth image
should be stored in millimeters and as 16 bit unsigned
integers. The following two formulas can be used for
converting raw-data to millimeters .

```
distance = 1000/ (− 0.00307 ∗ rawDisparity + 3.33 )
distance = 123.6 ∗ tan ( rawDisparity/2842.5 + 1.1863 )
```

Save each distance value to coressponding rawdisparty pixel. Save them as 16 bit unsigned grayscale png images. Check this [link](https://openkinect.org/wiki/Imaging_Information) for details.

Comment: Thanks for u r collaboration. But I have the depth image raw data which is the distance of pixel from sensor. Problem is that depth image only returns distance so if i get convert it in uint8 or any scaling method then it is proportional of distance. but this graph shows inversely proportional that means they got depth intensity somehow. I can extract distance but can not get depth intensity. Even i don't get anything about depth intensity in google.

Comment: @sufianahmed Sorry for late reply , I just noticed this comment. I looked to the paper the depth images looks like disparity images. Which is proportional to inverse depth. In theory disparity equals to d=b*f/z where b stands for baseline, f for focal length and z for depth.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

You can get the intensity by getting the intensity of corresponding IR pixel. let say you have a IR pixel array `irdata`,
then you can get the `intensity` of the `i`th pixel by

```
byte intensity = (byte)(irdata[i] >> 8);
```

In Kinect v2 only has two cameras, One is RGB camera and other one is IR camera. It uses IR camera to calculate the depth of the image by using the time-of-flight (TOF). If you need more information, please comment here or find my project on Kinect in github https://github.com/shanilfernando/VRInteraction. I'm more than happy to help you.

**Edit**

As you know depth is the distance between Kinect sensor to the object in a given space. The Kinect IR emitter emit bunch of IR rays and start counting time. Once the IR rays reflect back to the depth sensor(IR sensor) of the kinect, it stop the time counter. The time (t) between emission and receiving that specific ray is called the time-of-flight of that ray. Then distance (d) between kinect and the object can be calculated by

```
d = (t * speed-of-light)/2
```

This is done for all the rays it emits and build the IR image and depth image. Each and every ray represent a pixel in IR and depth images.

I read your reference paper, First of all, they are NOT using a depth image which is captured from the Kinect V2. It clearly said its resolution is 640 × 480 and effective distance range from 0.8 meters to 3.5 meters. 
I want you to clearly understnad, the depth frame and depth image are two different things elements. If you check the depth frame, each pixel is a distance and in depth image each pixel is intensity(How much bright/brightness).

In this plot they are trying to plot intensity of the star point against the actual distance of the star point. They are starting with a depth (intensity) image, NOT depth frame. depth frame you can scale in to a depth image where values are 0 to 255 where near points has higher values and further points has lower values.

Comment: kinect v2 has one rgb camera and another is Ir emitter and one is depth sensor , i think. someone suggest me this is just scaling between 0 to 255

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But what does depth sensor do? it calculate the flight time of the IR rays which emits by the IR emitter. So that IR emitter + depth sensor called IR camera.

Comment: and of course intensity is scaling between 0 to 255 and depth range scaling between 0 to 65536. But practically, kinect can't measure 65536 that far. its depth range is between 0.5m and 4m and FOV is 70.6 x 60 degrees. If you have access for IEEE articles, please check my article [http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7726202/](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7726202/)

Comment: "calculate the flight time of the IR rays" .. what does it mean sir ?..." intensity is scaling between 0 to 255"... nop sir i did not mean that. in the above picture u see that the depth intensity... someone suggest me this depth intensities are scaled from depth distance. is it right ?

Comment: @sufianahmed Yes, I edited my answer, please check it and let me know whether you understand it clearly or not. I can explain you further if you have any confusion.

Comment: Since it is hard for me to draw something in SO, please can you do a google search on "time-of-flight (ToF)" you will find good explanation about ToF

Comment: sir i understand ... but one thing is that, the depth intensity value is the scaled form of the distance value.. right ? then how can they take it as a feature. for example: they got two plots for upstairs and dwstairs respectively. they said one plot is feature for up and one for down. but for other stairs it will be worked or not ?...another thing is why they scaled depth distance and convert in depth intensity...depth intensity fully depend on depth distance... what benefit they got ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were trying to read depth from a Image file .png because of which the data is converted to binary form.

I would suggest you to save the depth image in **.tiff** format rather than **png** format.